# iOS RSS Parser issue

Tags: ios, rss

I was using [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-building-advanced-rss-reader-with-ios6/) RSS parser for iOS. I was trying to parse [this](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/rss.xml) news feed. I get the result but some of the HTML tags are also displayed in my view, like 
 "strong" and also some p tags.

I tried to look into the classes "GTMNSString+HTML" but could not figure it out how to fix the issue.

Is anyone using this parser and has same kind of issue? please share if you have gotten any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your parser.  The feed contains HTML.  You need to strip that if you don't want it.